# Shotwell imports photos to correct date folders but some wind up in No Event

Tags: 22.04, shotwell

In a fresh installation of shotwell 0.30.14, I specify that imported photo files should be placed in a YYYY/MM/DD directory structure. When I import files, I always have them copied to the structure. This works well. Also, photos are catalogued into the correct Event categories, with the same year, month, day structure; mostly. Some photos, however, are catalogued into the "No Event" event. Many of them are photos without proper date info in the metadata; some have no metadata at all. However, the problem is that some of the files that wind up in "No Event" do have usable metadata. Indeed, I have files that are created by the same camera on the same day; some are catalogued as year, month, day, while others wind up in "No Event". What's going on here? How does Shotwell determine the date of the photo? For example, exif Create Date?